# Laravel 5.4 validation unique issue

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique

I'm trying to update an user and when the email is already taken it will give an error, except when it's your own email. Right now my code is:

```
$user = User::find($id);

$input['email'] = request('email');

$rules = array('email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$user->id);

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email']);
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but now I want that it only gives an error if the email already exists AND from the found record the column 'function' = 'client', but I have no idea how to code this.

Comment: @tR4xX searching on google if someone has a solution, but I just don't know where and how to put it in the unique clause

Comment: did you mean only for `where function = 'client'` ?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham Yes, right now it always give an error when the email exists, but I don't want it to give an error if the column 'function' = 'client'

Comment: did you get this working already?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [Exist rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-exists) and [Unique rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique) from Laravel 5.4 doc

[image]

Then you can simply have:

```
//Import Rule
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

......

$rules = array( 'email' => array( 'required', 
    Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('function','!=', 'client');
    })->ignore($user->id)
));

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
```

I think the above should be sufficient even though I can't be 100% assure its going to fit your expectation but I think it should show you what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = User::where('email','=',request('email'))
        ->where('function','!=','client')
        ->count();

if($count){
    return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email' => 'Email Already Exist']);
}
```

**What will above code do :**

Count users whose email is `request_email` and function is not `client`.

if `$count` is greater than `1` that means duplicate `email`.

Return with error that `Email Already Exist`

Answer (score 0):

At this point you should use powerful Laravel's Validation.
According to documentation:

**The field under validation must be unique in a given database table. If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.**

And simply rule:

**unique:table,column,except,idColumn**

Code:

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$request->get('id').',id'
]);
```

Read more:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique